# HTML Height/Width Attribute Overwrite for Small Screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm embedding Addpipe recorder for a project and it takes Height and Width attributes in HTML, but that sets it to a fixed size and it's not scaling down for smaller screens. Is there any way to overwrite those set attributes in CSS or JavaScript?

I've tried setting the Height and Width attribute values to percentage and auto, but the recorder disappears. It needs to be either a `4:3` or `16:9` ratio. The website is made responsive using media queries. I need the dimension of the Piperecorder to change for screens smaller than 800px. I'm a beginner web designer, and would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

You can check out how it looks so far here: https://fewnew.github.io/YNWA-web

```html
<!-- begin video recorder code -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.addpipe.com/2.0/pipe.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.addpipe.com/2.0/pipe.js"></script>
<piperecorder id="custom-id" pipe-width="640" pipe-height="390" pipe-qualityurl="avq/360p.xml" pipe-accountHash="22864bed1e4827f6798d501706aeb89f" pipe-eid="1" pipe-mrt="120"></piperecorder>
<!-- end video recorder code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the `#video` then apply it to the recorder styles with jQuery in some easy steps:

First, create an IFEE and pass jquery `$` to it to prevent JS conflicts:

```
(function($){
    // next steps goes here...
})(jQuery);
```

Then create a function to get the source video styles, to apply it to the target video in the future steps:

```
(function($){
    // We set a name "setVideoStyles" to function to call it later with
    // this name.
    // We pass 2 arguments to it: sourceVideo and targetVideo
    // Later we pass '#video' as sourceVideo and '.pipeRecordRTC' as targetVideo
    function setVideoStyles(sourceVideo, targetVideo) {
        // Get sourceVideo (#video) width and height
        var videoWidth = $(sourceVideo).width();
        var videoHeight = $(sourceVideo).height();

        // Create an object with #video current styles
        // and set our variables to CSS, width and height are CSS attributes
        // which we can apply with jQuery
        var styles = {
            width: videoWidth,
            height: videoHeight
        }

        // Here we pass styles object as CSS method values with jQuery
        // for the target video
        $(targetVideo).css(styles);
    }     
})(jQuery);
```

Now we can use this function for all our purposes:

```
(function($){
    function setVideoStyles(sourceVideo, targetVideo) {
        var videoWidth = $(sourceVideo).width();
        var videoHeight = $(sourceVideo).height();

        var styles = {
            width: videoWidth,
            height: videoHeight
        }

        // Here we get screen width on each resize
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        // We check if screen is equal or smaller than 800px
        if(windowWidth <= 800) {
            $(targetVideo).css(styles);
        }
    }     

    // Now we use document ready to apply the styles when page loads
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setVideoStyles('#video', '.pipeRecordRTC');
    });

    // And window on resize to apply when the user resize the window
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        setVideoStyles('#video', '.pipeRecordRTC');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Feel free to ask any question.

**Note**: Please note I added an if statement which I forgot before.

**Note II**: Please review the IFEE part, I made some changes

Comment: Hi Ali. Thanks so much for your response to my question. I don't have any experience with jQuery so I'm just copying and pasting to see if I can get the result I'm going for. I'm still confused about one part: what values do I set for the height and weight attributes in the Piperecorder tag? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :)
Because your page included jQuery I provided the jQuery solution. The code above gets the first video tag width and height and applies its values to the piperecorder. I this solution you don't need to set any values by hand. For example `$(sourceVideo).width();` gets video element width and store its value to `videoWidth` variable, and as you see I set it to width property in `styles` object, then applied styles to the target video (piperecorder) by CSS by jQuery: `$(targetVideo).css(styles);`.

Comment: As you see `setVideoStyles` function used both in the document ready and window on resize, so every time page loads or user resize the page, the function runs. The function gets `#video` (the video id) and applies it to the piperecorder. So you just need to set correct styles to the video id to fix the piperecorder styles., because now they will have the same styles. More info about jQuery CSS: https://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: The main problem is this tag: <piperecorder id="custom-id" pipe-width="640" pipe-height="390" pipe-qualityurl="avq/360p.xml" pipe-accountHash="22864bed1e4827f6798d501706aeb89f" pipe-eid="1" pipe-mrt="120"></piperecorder>

Comment: When I remove pipe-width and pipe-height attributes the recorder disappears.

Comment: I read its documentation before I post my answer, and it does not have any responsive control, so we should leave it as it is and focus on the rendered element which is `pipeRecordRTC` class. Because it inherits the width and height from `<piperecorder id="custom-id">`. So when the recorder renders on the page we can set the styles with jQuery. If you inspect the recorder on the page using your browser developer tool you can see the styles: `<div id="pipeRecordRTC-custom-id" class="pipeRecordRTC" style="width: 640px; height: 360px; background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246); border-radius: 8px;">`